# How to erase all the properties of a symbol in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, plist

How can I completely erase from memory a property list? Ex.:

```
(setf (get 'book 'title) "Gone with the Wind")
(setf (get 'book 'author) "Margaret Micheal")
(setf (get 'book 'publisher) "Warner Books")
```

How do I delete all `'book`'s properties without calling `remprop` three times?

I tried to look into the HyperSpec but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
(setf (symbol-plist 'book) nil)
```

EDIT: After some searching, I came to the conclusion that modern CL code doesn't use `get` anymore in favor of [`getf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_getf.htm).

Comment: The symbol properties might be used by something else in the same image, so it would be better to only remove properties that you set yourself.

Comment: @jkiiski Would using `getf` instead of `get` be preferable?

Answer (score 2):

### Define an interface

You could define an API to manipulate your data without tying your code to a specific implementation. Example usage:

```
(defproperty title)
(defproperty author)
(defproperty publisher)
```

Then, set a title:

```
(setf (title :book-identifier) "Title")
```

Access the title:

```
(title :book-identifier)
```

Erase the title:

```
(setf (title :book-identifier) nil)
```

Erase all properties:

```
(erase-book-properties :book-identifier)
```

### Implementation

List of all properties:

```
(defparameter *properties* ())
```

As explained by [jkiiski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112881/how-to-erase-all-the-properties-of-a-symbol-in-common-lisp#comment81176421_47112986), only manipulate the properties that you own, don't touch at properties that might be added by other components:

```
(defun erase-book-properties (symbol)
  (dolist (property *properties*)
    (remprop symbol property)))
```

The `defproperty` macro:

```
(defmacro defproperty (name)
  `(progn
     (defun (setf ,name) (value symbol)
       (prog1 value
         (if value
             (setf (get symbol ',name) value)
             (remprop symbol ',name))))
     (defun ,name (symbol)
       (get symbol ',name))
     (pushnew ',name *properties*)))
```

### Refactoring

If later, you find out that you can also add title to instance of `book` classes, not only symbols, then you can change the implementation to add, e.g. generic functions to handle both symbols in a backward-compatible way, and other kind of objects.